# Maven compiler-plugin access forbidden

Tags: java, maven, maven-central

Suddenly I started seeing this error when running a maven project on Jenkins

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: 

Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 

Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.8.0 -> org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:pom:3.0.0-01: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:pom:3.0.0-01: 

Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler:pom:3.0.0-01 from/to bintray (https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven): 

Authorization failed for https://dl.bintray.com/groovy/maven/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-eclipse-compiler/3.0.0-01/groovy-eclipse-compiler-3.0.0-01.pom 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Has the POM changed since the last successful run? Has somebody changed something in _Manage Jenkins_: _Global Tools_ config, `settings.xml` or the like?

Comment: The downloads from `..bintray.com´ will not work anymore because they have closed the doors... First check your settings which source for download you are using ...if it's not configured there check the pom file and remove the entries with repositories.... from there...recheck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-eclipse-compiler](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-eclipse-compiler) is available on Maven Central which is also recommended on [its home page](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki/Groovy-Eclipse-Maven-plugin):

> Current version of the `groovy-eclipse-compiler` adapter: <kbd>maven-central</kbd><kbd>v3.7.0</kbd>